# A solution to link xls to ppt to have it working in both, Windows and Mac

Tags: excel

We have xls and ppt with the main calculation done in xls. The idea is to have graphs updated in ppt automatically. The issue is that there are both, Windows and Mac users having different versions of xls and OS. I have tried vba but it didn't work well because of the compatibility issue; I tried to embed graphs to ppt but it didn't work either because Mac doesn't support the embedded graphs and was throwing an error. Have you had this type of situation?

Comment: Mac does support the embedded objects but not if they are created on a pc. Also if created on a mac then it does not work on pc... different filesystems. And I tried it both ways.. Consider using a data file of csv and building the graph inside ppt...

Comment: That's bad news. Option 1 with csv won't work because there are many linked tabs in xls, and actually option 2 won't work for the same reason.

Comment: You lost me - what is option 2?

Comment: Consider using a data file of csv and building the graph inside ppt. Sorry, I thought 'Consider using a data file of csv' is option 1 and  'and building the graph inside ppt.' is option 2.